# Program to Read a Number n and Compute n+nn+nnn :Answer keep coming wih extra Zero

Tags: python

**strong text**        # Program explains cumulative same digit addition but problem is in 
        answer extra zero coming

```
    a = int(input("enter the number of units you want")) #number of times
    b = input("Enter the digit") #actual integer
    ans = str(0)
    z = 0
    for i in range(1,a+1):    #loop for number of integers
        for j in range(1):    #loop for repitation of integer
            ans=b+ans
        z = int(ans)+int(z)
    print("Ans is"+" "+str(z))
```

Comment: `ans = str(0)` should be `ans = ''`. If you don't want a `'0'` at the end, don't put it there.

Answer (score 0):

You had it nearly correct. The `range(1)` loop is not needed and `ans` should start empty not with 0.

```
a = int(input("enter the number of units you want")) #number of times
b = input("Enter the digit") #actual integer
ans = ""
z = 0
for i in range(1,a+1):    #loop for number of integers
    ans=str(b)+ans
    z = int(ans)+int(z)
print("Ans is"+" "+str(z))
```

Answer (score 0):

Say, for an input of 5 times with the digit 6, you want the output:

```
"66666"
```

Then just change

```
ans = str(0) to  ans = "" or ans = ''
```

Otherwise, if the output should be `30`, you want:

```
...
b = int(input(...))
ans = 0
...
```